# Code that compares two non-sorted int arrays. C

Tags: c, arrays, integer, return, compare

I need to create a code that compares two in arrays without sorting them. They have to be the same length and contain the same elements in any order.

- every integer in a[] is also in b[]
- every integer in b[] is also in a[]
- all such common values appear exactly the same
  number of times in both a[] and b[]

Examples:

- a = {1, 2, 3}, b = {2, 3, 4}    return 0
- a = {1, 2, 3}; b = {2, 3, 1}    return 1
- a = {1, 2, 2}; b = {2, 2, 1}    return 1
- a = {1, 2, 2}; b = {2, 1, 1}    return 0
- a = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2}; b = {2, 1, 2, 1, 2}    return 1

I just don't know what to do for this one...

Comment: What might you _think_ you need to do for this?

Comment: I don't know how to quite attack this one.. if I was allowed to sort the arrays this would be done in a few mins... but I just need help with implementation...

Comment: Are you allowed to use auxiliary storage? (If so, is there a limit?) Are you allowed to rearrange the elements in `a` and `b` in any way? Are the values in `a` and `b` arbitrary or restricted to a range?

Comment: I am not allowed to rearrange anything,  we can use auxiliary storage. The values in a and b are restricted to all pos. numbers

Answer (score -1):

You will end up with a quadratic algorithm if the arrays are not sorted. You can check array lengths at the beginning of your algorithm and if they are equal, say N, you would do something like this

```
      int result = 1;
          for (int j=0;j<N;j++) {
            bool found = false;
            for (int i=0;i<N && !found;i++) {
              if (a[j] == b[i]) found = true;
            }
            if (!found) return 0;
}
```

Comment: That won't correctly return 0 for the case `{1,2,2};{2,1,1}`

Answer (score -1):

```
I took sometime away and got it within a minute:D


int same_contents(int a[], int b[], int n){
int maxA=0,maxB=0,counterA=0,counterB=0;
int i,k,j,x;
for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    if (a[i]>maxA)maxA=a[i];
for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    if (b[i]>maxB)maxB=b[i];
if (maxA != maxB) return 0;
for(j=0;j<n;++j){
        counterA=0;
        counterB=0;
    for(k=0;k<n;++k){
        if(maxA==b[k])counterA++;
        if(maxA==a[k])counterB++;
    }
    if (counterA != counterB) return 0;
    else continue;
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Try that with `{1,2,2,3}` and `{1,1,2,3}` (or even with `{1,3}` and `{2,3}`). What's the point of the loop with `j`? `j` is not used anywhere.

Comment: I apologize you have to decrement maxA and maxB

Comment: Decrementing maxA and maxB will only work in reasonable time if the sets have restricted values. Otherwise, comparing {1,1000000000} with {2,1000000000} will take rather longer than one might want. If the values were restricted to small positive integers, there is a very pretty algorithm which is linear in the size of the sets, but I didn't provide it because the given constraint was that the sets were restricted to "all positive numbers".

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this!**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int check_same_array(int a[], int b[],int lenA,int lenB)
{
    int result = 0;
    bool flag = false;
    int i = 0,j=0;
    if (lenA != lenB)
        return 0;
    for (i = 0; i < lenA; i++)
    {
        flag = false;
        for (j = 0; j < lenB; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] == b[j])
                flag = true;
        }
        if (!flag)
        {
            result = 0;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (flag)
        result = 1;
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    int a[5] = { 2, 2, 3, 3 ,5};
    int b[5] = { 3, 3, 2, 2 ,5};
    int lenA = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
    int lenB = sizeof(b) / sizeof(int);
    printf("%d\n", check_same_array(a, b, lenA, lenB) && check_same_array(b, a, lenB, lenA));
    return 0;
}
```

`check_same_array` is used to check if each item in array A is in array B.
So if each item in array A is in array B,and each item in array B is in array A.
the item of the two array is same.

Comment: This does not treat repeated elements correctly, e.g. it compares {1, 1, 2} and {1, 2, 2} equal.

Comment: Let me take this into consideration.